# error in time command with zsh

Tags: command-line, 18.04, time, zsh

I am on Ubuntu:-

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

On terminal, I run this command:-

```
time -f "\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%S sys" ls -Fs
```

I get this error:-

```
zsh: command not found: -f
-f "\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%S sys" ls -Fs  0.00s user 0.00s system 76% cpu 0.002 total
```

I know this has got something to do with my zsh installation (zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)).

Can someone solve this issue?

Comment: `/usr/bin/time -f "\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%S sys" ls -Fs` should work.

Comment: See also: [Change the output format of zsh's time](https://superuser.com/q/71857/443564)